# How to clear ajax requests from network tab using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, console

I need to clear the ajax requests from network tab using jquery on any event like button click or using time interval. Is this possible?

Comment: If you mean network tab in browser, than **no**.

Comment: For sure it's possible. Download chromium source code and hack the developer-tools package. Do you really think you can hack things of your father box (browser) from the javascript?

Comment: As already mentioned you cannot manipulate the network tab of DevTools (except clearing it through page load, but that can be circumvented by checking "Preserve log"). If you don't want users to see the content of your ajax requests your best bet would be encrypting it. But to help with that we would need to know more about your backend (language, framework etc.)

Comment: All people are just discussing theories no solid logic or any demo/example.

Comment: People are discussing theories because you asked a theoretical question. Without providing code to work off of, you can't assume that people will write the code for you. That being said, the overwhelming number of people here are saying what you want is not possible. It's very hard to produce a demo/example of something that can't be done.

Comment: Of course it is not possible. Also, why you need this? There is no reason to hide network calls. If you worry about some security issues like restfull addresses, lookup data etc, you can share what you worry about. You will got more clear solutions, Be sure.

Answer (score 13):

If you mean the network tab in the browser's dev tools, then no, you cannot control it from Javascript. The dev tools are part of the browser and not part of the webpage, so Javascript has no knowledge of them.

This isn't directly related to your question, but this is evidence that the kind of thing you're looking to do would be very much not possible:

> We only allow explicit devtools opening.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112277

Answer (score 1):

I think, that's not possible but you can ensure you only send data in encrypted format (like md5 or something), so that no one can decrypt it even if the see it in network tab.

Still if you want, you can try some workaround. I guess, making JSONP call should work..they are not real ajax requests as they don't use XMLHttpRequest object, and they simply inject a script tag into the DOM.

Comment: MD5 is a hash function; It would be difficult to reverse the transformation ;)

Comment: Ohh Yes.. you could use base64 encode/decode  for your data with combination of other appended string/number